# Is Rich Dad Cashflow 202 the new version of Rich Dad Cashflow 101?

Tags: education

I was watching a TED talk about "Why the Rich get Richer" and the speaker mentioned a game called "Cashflow" that's like a financial simulator.  I noticed that there are two versions of it: one called Cashflow 101 (which has been discontinued) and another one called Cashflow 202.  Is 202 the same thing but just a newer version of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Cashflow* is a board game developed by Robert Kiyosaki designed to teach people how to become rich based on the advice in his *Rich Dad, Poor Dad* books.

*Cashflow 101* is the original game.  *Cashflow 202* is an advanced expansion pack to the original game.  It adds new cards and features to the game, but does not include a board, and you need the original *Cashflow 101* game in order to play.

---

It appears that the current edition of *Cashflow* (which was revised in 2014) is modified somewhat from the original *Cashflow 101* game, and I have no idea if the old *Cashflow 202* is compatible with the new edition of *Cashflow*.  But in any case, if you get ahold of a copy of *Cashflow 202*, it is not playable on its own.